# Types of (pcb) connectors

Tags: connector, interconnect

Is it easy to layout a PCB with this kind of connectors?

[image: http://www.1632bit.com/tools/Shop/UploadPhotos/201005/AC164124.jpg]

And what's the name of the female part of this type of connection?

Honestly, Im just lost in the interconnections world. What are the most common names for SMD and/or trough-hole connectors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a card edge connector, [here](http://uk.farnell.com/3m/3358-0001/card-edge-connector-socket-10pos/dp/1369088) is a typical example. PCB design using them is quite straightforward. They can be single-sided or double-sided. It's an example of a direct connector; there are also indirect connectors, such as the DIN41612.

Comment: Card edge connectors are fairly standard, but usually involve an extra fabrication step to gold-plate them, which many cheap fab houses don't offer.

Comment: You would typically create a Symbol for the connector and place it on the board, vs a bunch of individual pads.  It would plug into something like one of these https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/card-edge-connectors-edgeboard-connectors/303?k=card+edge+connector&k=&pkeyword=card+edge+connector&sv=0&pv88=20&sf=0&FV=ffe0012f%2C740002%2C1f140000&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25